# Clone org setup to other in cloud foundry

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

I want to create new organization in pivotal cloud foundry with existing org setup,

almost I want to copy the setup there from existing setup and  I need to deploy the application. Is there any command or some files replacement or I need to do it manually like creating fresh org,space and app?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the standard cf cli.

There is a cf cli plugin that does some of what you want. Take a look at the copy plugin: https://github.com/mevansam/cf-copy-plugin. It seems to copy a space to another space. You could loop that across all the spaces in your org and it should get you what you want.

Hope that helps!